# Gazebo crashes when starting

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to use the simulation environment "Gazebo". Unfortunately it crashes always when starting and the following error appears:

*[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 2912, exit code 139]*

My system:

- Lenovo L520
- Ubuntu 12.04
- ROS Fuerte
- Gazabo 1.6.16
- Intel HD Graphics 3000

I' ve read that Gazebo has problems with non-NVIDIA GPU's and particularly with integrated graphic chips from Intel. But when I tested Gazebo on my system a halfe year ago, it worked without any problems. So I think that the problem occurred sometime after an upgrade. Is there a possibility to run Gazebo on my current system or how can I come back to an older version? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63413/gazebo-crashes-when-starting/) by [platzhirsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3129/platzhirsch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-05-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [t.pimentel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4923/t.pimentel/) on 2013-05-24**:
Is that the only thing that shows up? Are there any extra errors? Is the gazebo server still working then?
Try running gzclient to see if the interface opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It might also be that you've upgraded your video driver since half a year ago through updates and the new driver is not supported.  Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried reverting to an older video driver?  I've had this issue before and it seemed to be resolved when I reverted to an older driver.

Not sure if you've used intel's driver application, http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-010512.htm

might help if your trying to revert to an older driver.

---

Originally posted by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) with karma: 325 on 2013-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0